# PHP script Quantity is not working properly and total is calculated wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

Need help with this script, it is not working.
I need Sub Total result  right it gives me wrong result and quantity of products is written same to all products in the cart.

```
 <td><input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['qty']) ? $_SESSION['qty'] : 0;?>"/></td>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";
        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty); 
        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;
        $total = $total*$qty;
    }                   
?>
```

Comment: Where is $total defined ? BTW, Your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Where is your `form` declaration ? Where is your $total declared ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isset` to test existence of variable, or index in this case

```
value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['qty']) ? $_SESSION['qty'] : 0;?>"
```

Comment: Thankyou panther . But there is another problem the quantity is registered the same in the database at all products added to cart. and total value is wrong. How to put this up same code with your correct code!

Comment: @ArdianHyseni: sorry, from the code you showed in question there is no chance how to help you more, you need more info and more of your code. Only idea, should be the default value in here 1 instead of 0? You  didn't mentioned if this code is from cart detail (I expect that), why session['qty'] isn't defined (how you create that), etc. When you create that base on real cart, it can't be undefined.

Comment: You forgot that you should do the check if it's empty or not.
while on most servers this will work.
ones with higher developement debugs will return an error. UNDEFINED $_SESSION['qty']

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>
```

This seems to outputting $_SESSION['qty'] without checking if its exists; any user who does not have a session set will not be able to show a value, which will crash the page, which will prevent a session from ever being set.

Check for the existance of variables and make sure they exist before you output them.

```
$qty_value = "";
if( isset( $_SESSION['qty'] ) ) {
  $qty_value = $_SESSION['qty'];
}
<input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $qty_value;?>
```

Comment: Erik can you help me more about this problem ? When I write the quaniy it send the same to all products .

Comment: You should ask another question with more information specific to the new problem you have. We don't know enough of your code to help you with this problem as it stands.